# Pandas Series: get all dates missing from a datetime slice or range

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

Given a `Pandas` series and a `datetime` slice or range of dates, how can I get all dates from the `datetime` slice or range that are in the `series` ?

```
Ex:
       #my date time slice/ date_range
       st = datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 31, 0, 0)
       en = datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 7, 0, 0)
       date_slice = slice(st,en) 
       rng = pd.date_range('08-31-2014', periods=8, freq='D')  

       #my series
       s = pd.Series({'09-01-2014': 1,
                      '09-02-2014': 1,
                      '09-03-2014': np.nan,
                      '09-04-2014': 1,
                      '09-06-2014': 1})
```

In this example I would like to return an array of dates in `str` or `datetime` format

```
['08-31-2014', '09-05-2014' , '09-07-2014']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DatetimeIndex.difference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.difference.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.difference) returns a sorted set difference:

```
In [573]: (rng.difference(pd.to_datetime(s.index))).format()
Out[573]: ['2014-08-31', '2014-09-05', '2014-09-07']

In [598]: (rng.difference(pd.to_datetime(s.index))).format(formatter=lambda x: x.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
Out[598]: ['08-31-2014', '09-05-2014', '09-07-2014']
```

Comment: What version of Panda's are you using? Maybe this was fixed in the more recent version but in `0.14.1` I don't get the desired result, I actually get the range of dates from `rng`

Comment: Same result using `rng.diff(s.index).format()` must be a bug with `0.14.1`

Comment: `s.index` is an Index of strings. You need to convert that into a `DatetimeIndex`. Are you calling `pd.to_datetime`, as in `rng.difference(pd.to_datetime(s.index)).tolist()`? (I'm using  version 0.15.1, but hoping that does not matter.)

Comment: Using minus symbol in pandas ver 0.20.3 raises ValueError: cannot add indices of unequal length. I used rng.difference(pd.to_datetime(s.index)) and solved the problem.